# What to do instead of async/await in a systems language

Tags: c, multithreading, async-await

I have a concrete problem that in a higher level language I would solve using async/await: we have a blocking system/hardware communication/network call that takes several seconds to complete. We would like to have that happen in the background while we do some other of such calls in parallel.

I have thought of a couple of solutions and there might be better ones than these:

1. start a thread and signal condition variable/semaphore once it's
   done;
2. provide a callback that is executed when the call finishes
   (old JavaScript style);
3. create your own custom scheduler to
   actually mimic async/await.

What's the ideal solution to this in a systems language such as Odin or C?

Comment: All of these are valid solutions and the "best" one will depend on your exact needs. It's not really possible to give a simple answer to this question

Comment: If there was an ideal solution, async/await would never have been invented :) All three are feasible solutions, or even a mixture.

Comment: Thanks for the quick comments. Is there any fourth way that I might be missing?

Comment: Polling while doing small parts of other things, but that is probably an espacially dirty variant of your 3.

Comment: Don't reinvent that wheel, it will be square.  Libuv is very popular.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using whatever asynchronous approach is most common in your system / language. I do not recommend using a separate thread, and I do not recommend trying to port a high-level style of asynchronous programming into a lower-level language / platform. You want your consumers using something that feels natural to them, rather than learning a whole new paradigm just to call your API.

If you're on Windows, you should be able to signal a `ManualResetEvent` on completion. Explicit callbacks would also be acceptable.

I haven't written asynchronous code on Linux, but I suspect adopting libevent or libuv would be the way to go.

If you're exposing an API for others to consume and you want it feeling the most platform-like, I believe you'd have to do that at the driver level. That allows you to fully implement support `OVERLAPPED` (on Windows) or `epoll` (on Linux).